# "Smart home" dystopian movie, AI locks in the inhabitant to protect him, probably from the 70ies

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, dystopia

I am looking for a movie title, the topic might best be called "smart home dystopia".

In the movie, there is an AI which controls the home/house/apartment, which also has the specific task to protect its inhabitant (a single man, at least I do not remember other family members).

This AI comes to the conclusion that the actual danger lies in the outside world and thus locks in the man to protect him. It follows some arguments between the man and the AI on this conclusion (AI explains her reasoning, etc.).

I have no recollection how the film ends. I remember I saw fragments of it on TV some 30 years back, from memory I would say it might be from the seventies.

I was not lucky searching for this title, any hints you might give me are appreciated.

Comment: Can you recall any of the actors? Also, are you sure it wasn't an episode of an anthology tv series?

Comment: Sounds like it was inspired by the highly influential Jack Williamson novella [*With Folded Hands.*](http://www.amazon.com/With-Folded-Hands-Jack-Williamson-ebook/dp/B006K2NE64)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not recall any of the actors.It could of course actually have been an episode of a TV series (feels somehow feels unlikely, but I will certainly consider it)

Comment: Possibly a scene from the 1970 movie [*Colossus: The Forbin Project?*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064177/) It's been a long time since I've seen the movie.

Comment: Colossus certainly sounds worth watching - but the setting (e.g. number of involved people) does not sound right.

Answer (score 1):

I also recall a movie like that as a kid from the 70s but I'm remembering different details. For example, a woman was impregnated by the computer house. It was called *[Demon Seed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed)*.

Could there be multiple movies like this from the 70s?

Answer (score -1):

Disney's [Smart House.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0192618/)

From IMDB:

> A 13 year old boy wins a computerized home manned by a cyborg maid named PAT. When he and his dad move into the house, he figures that his dad will cease considering re-marrying anyone since the house and PAT can handle all of the cooking and cleaning chores. However, his father soon shows an interest in the computer programmer. This sets the boy into tinkering with PAT's program and sets in motion a too wife (and mother)-like nagging robot.

This movie is from 1999 so it doesn't quite fit the time frame.

Comment: Definitely not possibly if OP saw it 30 years ago. The boy also doesn't fit if the original question is accurate.